# vmc installation mountain lion issue

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, cloud-foundry, vmc

I'm getting started with Cloudfoundry but even installing **vmc** I couldn't do it, I tried

```
sudo gem install vmc
```

and the terminal just goes silent, no error or report or anything.

what's wrong?

Comment: never mind apparently i need to update the gem

Answer (score 1):

Right, updating the gem will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait few minutes, depending to your download speed.

I had the same issues when changing my vmc version. It's took about 4 minutes then was ok.